# STL 2D Vector Fatal Runtime Error

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have the following code:

```
vector<vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(10);
vectObjVects[0].reserve(100);
```

During runtime, at the third line of my code, I get a 'Fatal Error' thrown by the line _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size());" in vector standard header which is presumably because it doesn't like me trying to index into vectObjVects before a size has been set.

What is the recommended way to reserve space in the inner vectors of a 2D-vector before any values have been filled in?

EDIT - Obj class added as per request:

```
class Obj
{
public:
Obj(int a, int b):iA(a), iB(b) {} 
Obj():iA(0), iB(0) {}
int iA;
int iB;
};
```

Comment: That looks valid to me. Which version of MSVC are you using? Also, is C++11 enabled? There used to be a defect in the standard with the above constructor which might still be present.

Comment: Are you using some old MSVC compiler ? And try using an iterator, might be some issue in using "[]" operator in this way

Comment: `vector<Obj> ObjVect;
vector<vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(10, ObjVect);` This is redundant, no? `vector<vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(10);` does the same thing since you default constructed `ObjVect`

Comment: I see no problem in the code. The initialization is fine. I don't think the validation error comes from line with reserve call. I suspect it might be from the Obj class...

Comment: Please post the constructors, assignment operator and destuctor for `Obj`.

Comment: @pmr: I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition "Version 9.0.30729.1 SP".  I haven't explicitly done anything to enable C++11 so unlessit is turned on as a default (which I doubt) then I'm pretty sure it's off!

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Good point, I can reduce the code to a single line. Edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be no errors in the code you have posted (see below).

The most likely explanations of your issue are:

- The code you've posted doesn't exactly match what you are running.
- Some other code that you think is unrelated is interacting with your vectors, possibly by corrupting the memory they are stored in.

My suggestion is that you use the debugger to examine the state of `vectObjVects` just before the call to `reserve`. If that looks OK, step into the code for reserve and see what the values of `_Pos` and `size()` are. They should be `0` and `10` - if they're not then that should point you in the right direction.

---

The following code compiles and runs exactly as expected:

```
#include <vector>

class Obj
{
public:
Obj(int a, int b):iA(a), iB(b) {} 
Obj():iA(0), iB(0) {}
int iA;
int iB;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(10);
  vectObjVects[0].reserve(100);
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply.

Quite honestly, apart from simplifying the object and container names I haven't changed anything in the code. There is also no gap in the code between the initialisation of the vectors and the call to reserve() and no other code can touch the vector (the only other thread is asleep).

I have taken the code you posted back and it runs fine in a new project. A key difference is the value of vectObjVects right after it is initialised. In my failing code it is [1](...,...) whereas in the code you posted it is [1]([0]()). Perhaps this sheds some light..?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, I changed

    std::vector<std::vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(10);

to

    std::vector<std::vector<Obj> > vectObjVects(1);

so that I could look at a simpler value (in both cases).

Comment: Does your code actually use a vector of *pointers* to vectors of Obj, rather than a vector of vectors of Obj?

Comment: No, it's definitely a vector of vectors of Obj.

Taken directly from my source code:
vector<vector<SimPocket> > playersSimPocketsVect(kNumPocketVectors);

Comment: When I expand the value for playersSimPocketsVect[0] (after initialisation) I get [0] = [3863365190]({iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{iA=??? iB=??? },{...  Very different from the nice and clean [0] = [0]() when I run your code seperately.

Comment: How strange. I manually rebuilt the project containing Obj, followed by the project containing the vector of vectors code and now it works ok. I have rebuilt the whole thing many times already (and the dependency is set to build the Obj project first). Baffling but at least it has fixed the problem. Hopefully it doesn't resurface at a later date. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you know how long the vector should be, you could use resize(), to reserve the demanded "space". Your code probably fails because ObjVect has no size, since the vector is empty.

Comment: `ObjVect` has a size. It's `0`. Also, `vectObjVects[0]` is supposed to refer to a copy of `ObjVect` not the object itself.

Comment: shouldnt it be "vectObjVects(10,ObjVect.size())", then?

Comment: That snippet is not going to compile unless `Obj` has an implicit converting constructor from a `size_t` or any type it can be converted to.